# How to specialize template functions for signed and/or unsigned arguments (std::is_unsigned)

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a short function to count the number of digits (integer portion) of a value.

```
template <typename T>
static size_t digits(T num) {
    auto is_fraction_of_one = [](T num) {
        return (num > 0 && num < 1) || (num > -1 && num < 0);
    };
    if (num == 0 || is_fraction_of_one(num))
        return 1;

    return std::is_unsigned_v<T> ? \
            static_cast<size_t>(std::log10(num)) + size_t(1) : \
            static_cast<size_t>(std::log10(num < 0 ? -num : num)) + size_t(1);
}
```

If `0 <= abs(num) < 1` it returns 1, otherwise it computes the number of digits via `std::log10(num)+1`.

The code works as-is, but the compiler (Windows VC++) warns:

> warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result
>   still unsigned

which is fair, since it doesn't recognize that the `-num` part in the last line will only execute when `T` is signed.

If I wanted rewrite the code to prevent this warning, how could I do it?

Since [std::is_unsigned_v](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned) is `constexpr`, I feel like I should be able to split the code into two separate template functions: one for when `T` is signed, and another for when it is not. But I can't figure out how to do it properly.

---

*Note:*

I realize I could shorten the code, and prevent the warning by casting `num` to a `double` (since `std::log10` will do that anyway without a template arg):

```
template <typename T>
static size_t digits(T num) {
    double dnum = std::fabs(static_cast<double>(num));
    if (dnum >= 0.0 && dnum < 10.0)
        return 1;
    return static_cast<size_t>(std::log10(dnum)) + size_t(1);
}
```

but I'm asking the question primarily for my own education. Also, I do have some other functions which would more aptly benefit from the solution (whatever that may be).

Comment: I've added a new answer to the dupe target that shows how you could leverage `if constexpr` instead of specializing the template.

Comment: @NathanOliver I can't comment to your answer (since I need 50 rep), nor can I upvote it (unfortunately), but it's perfect. I'm using c++17, and it keeps things very clean. Thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you out.  Hopefully it will help others as well

Comment: @NathanOliver Now I can upvote it! I'd better hurry before this question gets downvoted again, and I lose the opportunity:)